# Is FireStore collection.addSnapshotListener triggered by changes to nested documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For Firebase Cloud Firestore's collection addSnapshotListener:

```
mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
mFireStore.collection("someCollectionName").addSnapshotListener
```

if the `someCollectionName` contains a document which then contains another collection of documents, such as:

```
/someCollectionName/docID1203291030/nestedCollection/docID9040293094
```

if a document in the most nested collection of documents in modified, in this example `docID9040293094`, would this trigger the `someCollectionName` collection snapshot listener to retrieve the updated collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know listeners on a document are not triggered when a subcollection of that document is modified. You'll have to add a listener to the specific subcollection to get notified of such modifications.

Comment: In case of nested snapshot listeners on collections and subcollections, the change event will be fired n times on document changes. You can have duplicates in your result.